# Group objects if property values are the same

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to group the objects for the users that have the same `location` and `type` value shown in the example below. What would be the best way to approach this?

```
const diabetics = [
    {
        type: 'type 1',
        location: 'Boston'
        email: 'person1@gmail.com'
    },
    {
        type: 'type 2',
        location: 'New York'
        email: 'person2@gmail.com'
    },
    {
        type: 'type 1',
        location: 'Boston'
        email: 'person3@gmail.com'
    },
    {
        type: 'type 1',
        location: 'Maine'
        email: 'person4@gmail.com'
    },
]

// expected output 
const diabetics = [
    {
        type: 'type 1',
        location: 'Boston'
        email: [
        'person1@gmail.com',
        'person3@gmail.com'
        ]
    },
    {
        type: 'type 2',
        location: 'New York'
        email: 'person2@gmail.com'
    },
    {
        type: 'type 1',
        location: 'Maine'
        email: 'person4@gmail.com'
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also get the result using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), creating groups using a key composed of `type` and `location`.

Once we have a map keyed on type and location we can use Array.values() to return the desired result:

```js
const diabetics = [ { type: 'type 1', location: 'Boston', email: 'person1@gmail.com' }, { type: 'type 2', location: 'New York', email: 'person2@gmail.com' }, { type: 'type 1', location: 'Boston', email: 'person3@gmail.com' }, { type: 'type 1', location: 'Maine', email: 'person4@gmail.com' }, ]

const result = Object.values(diabetics.reduce ((acc, { type, location, email }) => {
   // Create a grouping key, in this case using type and location...
   const key = [type, location].join("-");
   acc[key] ||= { type, location, email: [] };
   acc[key].email.push(email);
   return acc;
}, {}))

console.log('Result:', result);
```